# Reel-to-reel audio tapes: calculating the percentage of a reel's length that has been used

Tags: geometry

My "reel"-world problem:

- I'm trying to calculate, for audio reel-to-reel tapes, what length of tape is on a reel, based on the diameter as measured from the center.
- The object in doing this is to be able to estimate how many minutes of sound have been recorded on a given tape reel
- The information I have is:
- the **thickness** of the tape (usually ca 1.0-1.5 mil)
- the **speed** at which the tape is recorded (usually 7.5 or 15 ips (in. per sec)
- the **total diameter** of the reel (usually 7" or 10.5")
- the number of inches (in diameter) of tape that are actually on the reel (e.g., reels are often not full; just a couple inches of the total effective reel diameter might be used.
- there are existing nifty charts I already have that give me the total time for a tape on a reel of x inches, recorded at y speed: 
  https://www.weareavp.com/open-reel-audio-duration-calculator/
- ... but, they assume FULL reels. I need to calculate the timing, based on a reel that is z-percent full.

I can't figure out how to calculate for the spooled tape - obviously, the closer to the center of the reel you get, the less tape length there is for each inch of reel diameter - but I don't know what formula I would need to use, to account for this.

So, if (for example) a full 7" tape reel recorded at 15ips = 15 minutes of audio, how much audio is it, if the reel is only 25% full? (e.g., only the first 25% of the total available reel diameter, measured from the center outwards, has been used?

Any help, Math Gods? This is not my strong suit, and, I've got hundreds of tape reels I need to estimate, for a digitization project (I'm a librarian).

Any tips, formulas, advice, pointers all greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the core radius of an empty reel. You are never going to get an exact length due to the tolerance on tape thickness and the error in measuring the radii. However a reasonable  approximation would be:

$$L = \frac{\pi(R^2 - r^2)}{\text{thickness}}$$  Where $R$ is the outer radius of the tape and r the inner radius or core radius of an empty reel.

And then $$t = \frac{L}{\text{speed}}$$ to get the time left on the tape.

Comment: Thanks for this info! Much appreciated.... I have hundreds of tape reels to estimate so this is a life-saver!